# I want to find my value in an array using just 1 foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array lets suppose

```
$myarr = array(
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4-7',
    '9',
    '10',
)

$search2 = '2';
$search5 = '5';
```

I want to check both these 2 variables inside my `$myarr`. The first one can be easily found by using `in_array` but the `$search5` is there inside '4-7' but what will I do to find the value? I **don't want 2 foreach** because i know I can use `explode` and then compare the start and end value. Is there a single or double line function that could help me achieve what I need? Thanks

Comment: i am waiting id some one posts a single or dual line function .. All i see is explode and compare

Comment: Then use one `foreach` and check both variables in each iteration and save the result in booleans…?!

Comment: @deceze i didn't understand

Comment: @deceze can you explain it more a bit?

Comment: @MAS `foreach ($myarr as $v) { if (/* check $search2 */) $search2Found = true; if (/* check $search5 */) $search5Found = true; } if ($search2Found && $search5Found) ...`

Comment: how would you handle the finding of `$search5` inside '4-7' ? :( @deceze

Comment: You already know that: *"use explode and then compare the start and end value"*

Comment: I dont get it? You dont want you use explode and compare start and end? You want some magic to to this with foreach ($myarr as $v){if(magic($search5))} ???? -- magic being someone implementing this in core php

Comment: If I have an array of 1 millions entries with just 2 or 3 ranges, I would have to check explode for 1 million entries? It would be crazy @deceze

Comment: Yes @DannyThunder I want some magic. I can't get the magic. Any ideas?

Comment: No, that would be normal. It would even execute so fast that you would never notice you just iterated a million values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**PHP code demo**](https://eval.in/768580)

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$search=2;
$result=null;
$myarr = array(
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4-7',
    '9',
    '10',
);
echo search_in_array($myarr,$search);
function search_in_array($myarr,$search)
{
    $result=false;
    array_map(function($number) use ($myarr,$search, &$result){
        if(preg_match("/^(\d+)\-(\d+)$/", $number,$matches))
        {
            if(in_array($search,range($matches[1],$matches[2]))) 
            {
                $result= true;
            }
        }
        elseif(preg_match("/^(\d+)$/", $number,$matches))
        {
            if(in_array($search,$myarr))
            {
                $result= true;
            }   
        }
    }, $myarr);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: @BilalAhmed Thanks... :)

Comment: Why `global`? [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) processes one item at a time. Why do you need the entire array in the callback?

Comment: i made it global to handle normal case When someone want to search for value `1` lets say

Comment: @axiac Please check second foreach for this.

Comment: You should use `use` to pass in external variables instead of `global`. The `elseif` branch makes little sense; why an expensive `in_array` if you could do a plain `$number == $search`? How does this address the two search conditions?

Comment: Woah. That is really good! Who down voted ? It works perfectly! Waiting For OP to agree

Comment: @SahilGulati, can you convert this into a function?

Comment: Do you want me to convert it into function which will return `true` for found or `false` for not found?

Comment: @UzumakiNaruto 2  persons downvoted my answer i dont know why they have done this just for no reason

Comment: @SahilGulati yes I was trying myself to convert it to a function that returns true or false but I couldn't. Some Problem with global variables. Can you convert it into a function?

Comment: @UzumakiNaruto I have updated my post can you please check.

Comment: @SahilGulati  NICE WORK BUDDY :)

Answer (score 1):

Just as another answer:

```
$myarr = [
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4-7',
    '9',
    '10',
];

$search2 = '2';
$search5 = '5';
$search12 = '12';

function myInArray($needle, $haystack) {
    return in_array(
        $needle,
        array_reduce(
            $haystack,
            function($incrementor, $value) {
                return array_merge($incrementor, (strpos($value, '-') !== false) ? range(...explode('-', $value)) : [(int)$value]);
            },
            []
        )
    );
}

foreach([$search2, $search5, $search12] as $searchValue) {
    echo $searchValue, " is ",(myInArray($searchValue, $myarr) ? '' : 'NOT '), "in the array", PHP_EOL;
}
```

Probably not as efficient, especially when working with larger ranges of values in `$myarr`, but a slightly different approach

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Sa8h2)

Comment: can we avoid explode by any chance?

Comment: You can avoid using `explode()` by replacing it with `preg_split('/-/', $value)`, but it's still just doing the same thing; in practise, you can't avoid splitting when using this method

Comment: Thank you for this *range(...explode('-', $value))* . I was searching all over for this but I found here.

Comment: Alternatively, replace `range(...explode('-', $value))` with `range(sscanf($value, '%d-$d'))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is almost one-liner,

```
$search = '5';
$matches  = explode('-',array_values(preg_grep('/[-]/', $myarr))[0]);
if(in_array($search, $myarr)|| in_array($search,range($matches[0],$matches[1]))){
    echo "found";
}else{
    echo "not found";
}
```

I am exploding by `-` and then creating range with that and checking that with in_array.

Here is working [DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f4d72fdbc973e36e74fe03fd04f0a5d20e1b62a3)

Comment: by any chance can we avoid explode?

Comment: Is there any such criteria to avoid ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code :

```
$myarr = array('1','2','3','4-7','9','10');

$search = 1;        // Try with 5 

$flag1 = false;
foreach($myarr as $number){
    if(!is_numeric($number)){
        list($start,$end) = explode("-",$number);
        if($search >=$start && $search <=$end ){
            echo $search .' Found';
        }
    }else if($flag1 == false){
       if(in_array($search,$myarr)){
           echo $search .' Found';
           $flag1 = true;
       }
    }
}
```

[**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/768431)

Comment: I tried $search = 2; $search1 = 5; and the code crashed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$myarr = ['1', '2', '3', '4-7', '9', '10'];
$search_array = [2, 5];
$search_results = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($search_array); $i++) {
    $search_results[$search_array[$i]] = array_search($search_array[$i], $myarr);
    if (!$search_results[$search_array[$i]]) {
        foreach ($myarr as $value) {
            if (strpos($value, "-") !== false) {
                $data = explode("-", $value);
                if ($search_array[$i] >= $data[0] && $search_array[$i] <= $data[1]) {
                    $search_results[$search_array[$i]] = array_search($value, $myarr);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (!$search_results[$search_array[$i]]) {
        unset($search_results[$search_array[$i]]);
    }
}
var_dump($search_results);
```

Obviously using single foreach i cam up with this code to find ...  set of data another is for loop not foreach.

Comment: I know this method. I needed the magic function. This is not the magic function that I wanted.

Comment: This is the best i could write .. I liked @sahilgulati's code

Answer (score 0):

@Ali Zia you can also try this logic like below:

```
<?php
    $myarr = array(
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4-7',
    '9',
    '10',
    );
    $flag = 0;
    $search = '5';

    foreach($myarr as $value){
        if($value == $search){
            $flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        else if(strpos($value, "-")){
            $numberRange = explode("-", $value);
            if($numberRange[0] <= $search && $numberRange[1] >= $search){
                $flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if($flag == 1){
        echo "yes number found in the array";
    }
    else{
         echo "sorry not found";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of using `range()` and argument unpacking, because none of the other answers do:

```
function in_array_range($needle, array $haystack) {
    if (in_array((int) $needle, $haystack, true)) {
        return true;
    }

    $haystack = array_map(
        function($element) {
            return strpos($element, '-')
                ? range(... explode('-', $element, 2))
                : (int) $element;
        },
        $haystack
    );

    foreach ($haystack as $element) {
        if (is_array($element) && in_array((int) $needle, $element, true)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function below returns the index of `$needle` in `$haystack` or `-1` if no such element has been found.

```
function find(array $haystack, $needle) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($haystack); $i++) {
        $parts = explode("-", $haystack[$i]);
        if (count($parts) == 2) {
            if ($needle >= $parts[0] && $needle <= $parts[1]) {
                return $i;
            }
        }
        else if ($needle == $parts[0]) {
            return $i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The function assumes that `$array` only contains a single non-negative integer or two non-negative integers separated by a dash.

You can now collect the indices like this:

```
$indices = array();
foreach ($searchValues as $searchValue) {
    $indices[] = find($myarr, $searchValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer has already been accepted but here is my approach w/ and w/o using foreach.

([See demo](https://eval.in/768612)).

With foreach :

```
<?php
$value = 3;
    foreach($myarr as $myval){
    list($start, $end) = strpos($myval, '-') ? explode('-', $myval) : [$myval, $myval];
    if($value >= $start && $value <= $end){
        echo $value . ' found between "' . $start . '" & "' . $end . '" !' . "\n";
    }
}
```

Without foreach, "one line" code :

```
<?php
$value = 5;
$trueValues =  [1,5];
$falseValues = [5, 7, 8];
var_dump(!count(array_diff($trueValues,array_reduce($myarr,function($arr, $item){return $arr + (strpos($item, '-') ? range(...explode('-', $item)) : [$item]);},[]))));
var_dump(!count(array_diff($falseValues,array_reduce($myarr,function($arr, $item){return $arr + (strpos($item, '-') ? range(...explode('-', $item)) : [$item]);},[]))));
var_dump(in_array($value, array_reduce($myarr, function($arr, $item){return $arr + (strpos($item, '-') ? range(...explode('-', $item)) : [$item]);}, array())));
```

Unfolded :

```
<?php
var_dump(
    !count(
        array_diff(
            $trueValues,
            array_reduce(
                $myarr,
                function($arr, $item){
                    return $arr + (strpos($item, '-') ? range(...explode('-', $item)) : [$item]);
                },
                []
            )
        )
    )
);
```

EDIT : Didn't know the ellipsis operator, thank you @Mark Baker